# Highcharts: Pie chart label overlap

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I have this pie chart: http://jsfiddle.net/gXjVY/

And as you can see, the data labels of the charts are overlapping. I tried to define the `distance: -1` inside a serie, but it doesn't work. Anybody an idea, how I can define different positions, or distances for the series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set for series, not for a point, different distances, see: http://jsfiddle.net/gXjVY/3/

```
series: [{
    data: [...],
    dataLabels: {
        distance: -30
    }
}]
```