# Pie chart data labels are hidden for smaller values

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am working on a Highcharts where I need to show data labels for small and large values. But for some reason, data labels are getting hidden. The last, third & fourth last 1's are getting hidden in the pie chart

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/y9fdrpoj/42/)

I tried a few things

1. Distance property [fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295279/highcharts-pie-chart-label-overlap)
2. Used crooked distance [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-datalabels-crookdistance/)
3. And custom  [formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382352/highcharts-datalabels-connector-customization-straight-line)

Code:

```
const options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    height: 340,
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  plotOptions: {
    /* series: {
      dataLabels: {
       distance: 20,
        style: {
          textOutline: false,
          fontWeight: 'normal',
          fontSize: '14px'
        },
        allowOverlap: true
      },
      style: {
        fontSize: '14px'
      }
    }, */
      pie: {
     //   alignTo: 'PlotEdges',
   //  cumulative: -0.25, // Start at 3PM
     //   borderWidth: 0,
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 180,
       // cursor: 'pointer',
        center: [0, 125],
         
          /*   dataLabels : {
                rotation : 15
            }, */
        
        /*  dataLabels: {
                distance: '90%'
          }, */ 
          
       
      }
    },
  series: [{
      innerSize: 155,
      size: 205,
      data: [85,5,1,1,2,1],
      //startAngle: 45
       
    }, {
      innerSize: 105,
      size: 155,
      data: [87,2],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }],
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      shared: true,
      outside: true,
      hideDelay: 700,
      shape: 'square',
      followPointer: false,
      formatter: function () {
        return "<span>" + this.key + ' ' + this.y + "</span><br/>"
      }
    },
    
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options);
```

Version: 7.0.1

Comment: Where is you pie char cut in half ? in that how you wanted to look ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yes it should look the same way as half cut

Comment: Thats what causing the labels to hide .As far as i know there is no alternative to that. Unless you change your mind and set the endAngle to `150`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I cannot change the angle to 150 cuz I need the half semi-circle which should be always 180. Also, even if I change the angle to 150 still the data labels are not visible

Comment: Have you considered to implement one of the solutions which are described here? https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/pie-datalabels-alignment

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Yes I tried the most of the solution from this link but it didn't work out except the last solution provided in the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting padding to 0 should fix your issue.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1gj73hvz/

```
series: {
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
            padding: 0
  },
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.padding